# On the install screen, it says “Started Run anacron jobs”

Tags: system-installation

I’ve left the elementary OS on the install screen for 18> hours now and it’s still stuck on the update-grub phase of the install. Did I do something wrong?
I just purchased the download and I thought it would be easy to install.
[image: image of the lines]